# Change cache location when publishing a service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cache, publishing

When publishing a service on arcmap how do you change the cache location? Since when a service is cached there is no way to change the option available from the default option. 
I went to Customize, Arcmap Options and Display Cache and I changed the path there however this did not change the path that shows the cache location when I come to publish the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcMap's cache is not used for storing the cache of services you publish, it's used to store tiles of services you use in ArcMap.

If you want to manage you map service cache, there are 2 options:

- you define cache options when publishing the service in ArcMap
- you modify an existing cache with the [Caching toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/server-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-caching-toolset.htm) in ArcToolbox

More in detail:

1. When publishing your service in ArcMap, click the 'Caching' tab on the left of the Service Editor window (see 1 in the first image below). Choose to use tiles from a cache (2), then to build the cache automatically when the service is published (3). Click the Advanced Settings tab under Caching in the left pane (4) and finally set your cache directory (5).

   Cache locations available in (5) have to be defined in advance in the Server Manager (see second image below). Log in to the Server Manager, click Site (A), then either change the default cache directory by clicking the Edit icon next to it (B) or add a new cache location by adding a directory (C). In the Add Directory window, choose cache as directory type (D), a location (E), and a name.
2. To modify an existing cache, take a look at the [Caching toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/server-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-caching-toolset.htm) in ArcToolbox. You can move your existing cache with [Import Map Server Cache](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/server-toolbox/import-map-server-cache.htm) and/or [Export Map Server Cache](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/server-toolbox/export-map-server-cache.htm). You could also choose to not create the cache when publishing the service (other option in step 3 above) and create it manually afterwards with [Create Map Server Cache](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/server-toolbox/create-map-server-cache.htm).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe I may not have been very clear in what I asked. My issue isn't how to create the cache for the service, but it is to change the cache directory as in your number 5. When selecting the dropdown list no options are available to choose a different directory.

Comment: In your question you're talking about the ArcMap cache, so I thought a complete answer on how to manage service cache settings wouldn't be useless. I've updated my answer to include how to define cache locations available in step 5.

Comment: I noticed in your answer you have both a drive C and a drive D which I am guessing are different drives. Did you have to do something to make this possible as when I use a drive other than C I get the following error: Failed to register the server directory 'MIPCache'. Cannot write to directory path 'Z:'. Please check that the location is valid and that the ArcGIS Server account has permissions to the location.

Comment: There's a C and and a D drive on my server (I've chosen the first path I could think of for my example). If you want to store your cache on a location that is not your server, I advise you to read this carefully: [Make your data accessible to ArcGIS Server](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/making-your-data-accessible-to-arcgis-server.htm)